# Function keys on Asus Zenbook prime

Tags: drivers, keyboard, asus-laptop, zenbook

I've been using my Asus Zenbook Prime for about 2 years and now and recently I've noticed that the custom function keys will quit working occasionally. For those who don't know, by holding down Fn + a function key you can do various things such as increase/decrease volume, increase/decrease screen/keyboard brightness etc...

If I restart my computer they work fine again. It seems to happen if I put my computer to sleep and then start using it again. I've uninstalled/reinstalled the driver for the hotkeys. The driver's called ATKACPI.

Any thoughts on what's going on?

EDIT:
When you use the hotkey's a little graphic appears on the screen telling you what you're doing. The screen brightness controls however continue to work even when the rest of them don't. However the graphic is not shown.

Comment: What's the exact model?

Comment: Asus Zenbook ux31A

Comment: And what's the operating system?

Comment: Windows 7. Up to date and whatnot.

Comment: Make sure to install latest drivers/utilities from the [official support page](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=UX31A&os=30): **ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities** (V1.0.0027) / **Keyboard Device Filter Utility** (V1.0.0.3).

Comment: I have done this but they stop working after I put my computer to sleep a couple times.

Comment: Is Hybrid Sleep enabled?

Comment: nope. I reinstalled Windows a while back and only installed the essential drivers.

Comment: Try enabling hibernation (in case it's not already), and hibernate Windows. See whether you get the same issue after resuming.

Comment: I was unable to replicate the problem by hibernating. I also noticed that it doesn't happen if I immediately put the computer to sleep after restarting it. Now that I noticed that, apparently it only happens if I leave the computer in sleep for any significant amoutn of time. (overnight for example.)

Comment: Looks like it's a driver issue. What's the BIOS version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12878/discussion-between-and31415-and-codedude)